# error: expected ‘while’ before ‘return’, Have equal amounts of closing and opening {}s and cant find the proble

Tags: c

error: expected ‘while’ before ‘return’
return 0

I can't figure why it asks for a "while" before return

Tried nesting the code differently and can't find it work.

```
int random;
    int userinput;
    random = rand() % 1000 + 1;

    do 
    {
    printf("Can you guess the random number? \n");
    scanf("%d", &userinput);

        if (random >= userinput)
        {   
            printf("The number you entered is too high! Try again! \n");
        }

        else if (random <= userinput) 
        {
            printf("The number you entered is too low! Try again! \n");
        }

        while (random!=userinput)
        {
           printf("You guessed it! Correct! The number is: %d \n", random);
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Exactly what it says.  You have a `do` with no matching `while`.  `do{...} while( cond ) ;`

Comment: `do` requires a `while` at the end of the code block.

Comment: Also your logic and equalities look incorrect.  The `while (random!=userinput)` should be just `else` (no condition), and the preceding conditions `>` and `<` rather than `>=` and '<=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `do` in your loop and it requires a `while(condition)`. Here's a sample loop to execute your statements while userinput is not equal to the random number:

```
do {

 // your statements

} while (userinput != random);

return 0;
```